# Getvalue from dynamic keys in Gson

Tags: android

I have one Registration Api which has error object in which it shows Errors Dynamically in Array.

This is the JsonFormat of Api :

```
    {
    "status_code": 422,
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        "errors": {
            "password": [
                "The password must be between 8 and 15 characters."
            ],
            "mobile_no": [
                "The mobile number has already been taken."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here if a user forgot to write name then it will show username array in errors. So it changes dynamically.
My question is how I can set this type of errors in gson.I am using retrofit to call Api.
I did this in my Data class but it showing me errors.

```
 @SerializedName("errors")
@Expose
JsonObject errorObject;

Iterator iterator=new Iterator() {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        Iterator keys=errorObject.keys();
        if(keys.hasNext()){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please help me how can I getErrors using gson.Thank u

Comment: In your responseModel prepare all state of error and then in code based on status_code do different things.

Comment: I also thought this way but its a very long process.and if they add any new error then I also need to add that state of error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` to maintin the datastructure like this:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(yourErrorsArrayHere, type);
```

and then just use `myMap.get("your_error_key")` to get the particular error.

Comment: I am not sure which error will popup . So basically I need to get all type of errors.and if any particular error will be null then it will give nullpointerException ?

Comment: In a particular moment, if you are interested to know whether some error occured you willl know the key to ask. Otherwise, you can be interested if any error occured at all, in that case you can check the size of the map. I don't get your doubts, please clarify.

Comment: I will try this first, will let you know if I get any error in this.Thank you